# c++ error in included files

Tags: c++, xcode, header-files, c++-chrono

I am receiving errors in 2 C++ header files. The files are chrono and _mutex_base. I haven't directly included them in my code, but they appear to have been included by way of iostream.

I'm not exactly sure how I should post them, I'll include the lines with errors below:

```
// in <chrono>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR _Rep zero() {return _Rep(0);} // Expected member name or ; after declaration specifiers
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR duration zero() {return duration(duration_values<rep>::zero());} // Expected member name or ; after declaration specifiers
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 time_point() : __d_(duration::zero()) {} // Expected unqualified-id
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR time_point max() {return time_point(duration::max());} // No member named 'max' in 'std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> >'

// in <__mutex_base>
if (__d <= __d.zero()) // Expected unqualified-id
    return cv_status::timeout;
```

Any idea what I should do to fix this?

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1, I believe that is the latest version.

Comment: You appear to have a conflict on `zero` and `max`.  Do you have macros defined somewhere that redefine them?  Without seeing the code that causes the issue it's pretty hard to do anything but guess.

Comment: Yes, just realized I had done `#define zero`, and I may have done something similar with `max`... that has caused it?

Comment: It's very likely.  Try to avoid macros, they have no namespace so they can easily break tons of other unrelated code.

Comment: That fixed it. I wasn't aware of the potential danger with macros, however I'll avoid using them in the future. Thanks!